# Review certain tags by default for eminent migration?

Tags: discussion, review, migration

Is it possible for Stack Overflow to always review certain tags by default?

I've noticed that question tagged with [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) rarely have a programming question. Most questions inquire how to configure it.

I've noticed similar from [openssl](/questions/tagged/openssl), but its not nearly as bad. Many OpenSSL questions inquire how to use the built-in utilities (e.g., s_client, rsautil, x509, etc), and how to operate PKI like self-signed certificates and server certificate verification.

Would it be possible to move questions tagged with [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) or [openssl](/questions/tagged/openssl) into the review queue when they are asked?

Or perhaps two new tags could be used that triggered the move: [nginx-config](/questions/tagged/nginx-config) and [openssl-utils](/questions/tagged/openssl-utils). That is, when the tag is added to a question, automatically move it into review status in preparation for migration to another site on the Stack Exchange.

(And I imagine other technologies suffer similar. I'm just not that familiar with them).

Comment: The problem is most off-topic questions are not suitable for migration, and should be closed.  So you are effectively pre-judging a post to be close-worthy only based on the fact that it includes specific tag.  Not sure how I feel about this yet.  Some specific stats might be useful.

Comment: "The problem is most off-topic questions are not suitable for migration" - I'm wondering if that's the case for some of these tags (I probably agree in general, though). Just for fun, cruise through the latest 30 or 50 nginx questions. I don't think they are bad such that a close is in order. My [possibly incorrect] opinion is most belong on Server Fault.